# ensureCapacity not recognized

Tags: java, list

```
import java.util.*;
class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
    private List <B> bList;
    private Random generator = new Random();
    A(List<B> initialList){
        bList = new ArrayList<B> ();
        int listSize = initialList.size();
        bList.ensureCapacity(listSize);
             for (B b : initialList) {
             int bIndex = generator.nextInt(listSize);
             bList.add(bIndex , b);
        }
    }
}
class B{
}
```

I have been getting the error reading

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:  Uncompilable
>   source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.List.ensureCapacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDE's are always good to have,Time is precious if you are using any IDE to program definitely you will get a red mark on this `bList.ensureCapacity(listSize);` line with a message  which will secure your time to find out the solution the message clearly saying that `ensureCapacity(int)` is undefined for List interface.

```
The method ensureCapacity(int) is undefined for the type List<B>
```

So `ensureCapacity(int)` method is available inside the implementation of List interface which is ArrayList, Cast your this line(bList) `bList.ensureCapacity(listSize)` to `((ArrayList<B>) bList).ensureCapacity(listSize);`

Answer (score 2):

ensureCapacity is not a method of type List.

And yes It's a method of ArrayList,but the reference bList is a List,you should cast it to ArrayList to use that method,like this:

```
((ArrayList<B>) bList).ensureCapacity(listSize);
         for (B b : initialList) {
         int bIndex = generator.nextInt(listSize);
         bList.add(bIndex , b);
    }
```

By the way,I never invoke the method ensureCapacity of ArrayList directly  in my entire program life.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` is an interface, but it does not contain definition of `ensureCapacity`. This is available in `ArrayList` and `LinkedList<T>` - so you have to cast the `bList` to `ArrayList` to call `ensureCapacity`.

```
((ArrayList<B>) bList).ensureCapacity(listSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call ensureCapacity on the List then you should declare it as an ArrayList not a List.

Casting, generally speaking, should never be done if you can avoid it.  You should declare you variables to be as general as they can be without needing to resort to casting.  That isn't always possible, but in this particular case there is no reason not to do so.